# C# - Extract speciifc div class text using HTMLAgility

Tags: c#, html, css, html-agility-pack

I have a code in C# where I want to extract the below value (the text "I want this text" in the HTML code below). I have reformat the HTML code to make it easily readable.

```
<div class="paste-copy-url" style="margin:0 0 0 0;">
    <h4>My Stats:</h4>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="wrap-input">
            <input onclick="this.select();" value="I want this text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Website Link:</h4>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="wrap-input"><input onclick="this.select();" value="Some value" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code I tried (It is giving me the text : "Website Link:"):

```
var myvaluetoextract = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='paste-copy-url']");
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I use this approach to get that element (There is only 1 instance of the div class in the page)?

Comment: did you mean that `myvaluetoextract` is `null`...The above xpath is correct and should work..

Comment: It is giving me the text : "Website Link:" (the header instead of the value I want)

Comment: @touyets you said `returns a null value`,now say `It is giving me the text : "Website Link:"`. Which one is correct?

Comment: I edited my post. The correct one is this result after I corrected the page's url: It is giving me the text : "Website Link:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var input = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
           .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='paste-copy-url']//div[@class='wrap-input']/input");
var yourText = input.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Comment: it gives me the value "Some value" which is the value for the second element, not the first which is the one i want.

Comment: @touyets No it returns `I want this text` given your sample html in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var myvaluetoextract = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='paste-copy-url']//input");
var value = myvaluetoextract.GetAttributeValue("value", null);
```

`//input` means you search for `input` elements in the `div`'s subtree, recursively. `GetAttributeValue` is a helper that will never fail, even if the attribute doesn't exists (in this case if will return the 2nd passed parameter - which is `null` here)

Comment: it gives me the value "Some value" which is the value for the second element, not the first which is the one i want.

Comment: Then your extract does not match your real code. My code works with the html in your question.